# Failed for being unable to edit a Review Test

Tags: feature-request, review

I was reviewing [this first post](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/408258), here is a screenshot:

> [image: Test review]

It wasn't exactly as the image above - no comment nor votes were shown and there were the usual `share edit flag` links underneath.

Anyway, I went to edit it, in order to blockquote the text from here [InitLocalMsCtfMonitor function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa966199.aspx) and inline the link . However, when I tried to edit it, I got the message that the post had been removed.

So, I then clicked on the **I'm done** message (actually it may have been **No action needed** as the **I'm done** could have been greyed out - I don't remember precisely and I obviously can not reproduce the issue), both of which seemed valid responses, as there was nothing further that I could do, and I didn't want to **Skip**. I was then presented with:

> [image: You failed!]

What should I have done to avoid this failure? I assume *Downvoted* or *Skipped*, in lieu of **I'm Done** or **No action needed**?

Should the *checking system*, somehow, not take account of attempted edits? Although, I must admit I'm not sure how that would be implemented - maybe by checking for a click on the `edit` link beneath the question?

This is just my initial impression as, while I have been editing posts for over 6 months, I am relatively new to the Review queue.

Comment: +1 because it's nice that you're doing some reviews, this is what makes the sites and their content better for all. And also good for asking, rather than ranting, ignoring the issue, or giving up with reviewing. It can be tricky to get your head around some things, but at first just make sure you are 100% sure you know what a review requires, and anything you are unsure about at all, click "skip" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I tried to edit it, I got the message that the post had
>   been removed.

So this was a *hint* that you are doing the wrong thing. And while audits can be tricky beasts, in this case it was pretty fair.
It didn't just fail you, as that would be unfair as an edit could potentially be the *resolve*, but it was fair and essentially returned: "Uh uh, are you sure that is what you want to do".

When you have reviewing experience, upon discovering the post has been removed you will realise it's an audit, but even if not, as you knew the answer was deleted you follow suit and: Downvote, or click delete, etc.

If it wasn't an audit, and the answer was still there, your edit may well have resolved the issue and been a perfectly valid and good outcome for the site and review.
But again, you were told the answer no longer exists, either by clicking "edit" or viewing the full question (out of the review).

Your clicking "no action needed" was because you thought "the answer is no longer there so the problem is resolved".
And while your logic is valid in one sense, you are in a review scenario, and are being asked "what action should be performed on this answer".
Reviews are not about confirming if the outcome is valid (when it's an audit of course), it's about reviewing the content presented to you.

So stating "no action needed" on a review of a deleted post is like stating "this answer is fine", and the site knows the answer has been deleted (as should you) and so deemed that review choice to be bad.

---

> Should the checking system, somehow, not take account of attempted
>   edits? Although, I must admit I'm not sure how that would be
>   implemented - maybe by checking for a click on the edit link beneath
>   the question?

Again, the review/audit allowed you to click edit without a problem to you - it just told you "You cannot do that as the answer is deleted".
This is all the info you needed really.

Knowing it was deleted or not aside, in this scenario the audit presented you with an answer which had a downvote, and not much text and a link.
In my experience this scenario (in audits and reviews) is cause for a quick look at the question to see what the question asked, and how the answer fits in with it.
You then see the answer is gone, and know it's an audit and so *smugly* click "delete" or "downvote" etc.

If the answer was still there, with it having a downvote and it being almost *link only*, then an edit adding more info would be fine, or downvote, or delete.

The audit system is not perfect, and sometimes can trip us up a bit.
It's just to prevent the most obvious "robo-reviewer", and even though the site shows the answer has been deleted, the fact you went to the question and discovered this means you are "paying attention" and not just coming to the review and immediately clicking a choice without doing anything else.

You just chose the wrong thing on this occasion - happens to most of us, especially when learning about audits and what the review system wants from us.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer: _Your clicking "no action needed" was because you thought "the answer is no longer there so the problem is resolved"._ is quite right, however, yo be fair, I assumed that the poster of the answer had deleted the answer themselves (maybe they realised that it wasn't good enough), rather than the fact that it had already been reviewed. I'm up voting your answer but I'm not sure why your answer has been down voted - I would like to see if the down voter has a different explanation, but we may never know... :-)

Comment: There is nothing to be fair about,  I was not being harsh, just factual ;) I know how tricky the audits can be and they've caught me out plenty too. There was another post recently same as yours, and the answer had been deleted by the answer author. Which on one hand is wrong, because "no action needed" but the same applies really, if you know the answer is deleted, then the site deems the answer to be "bad", so review accordingly. It's not ideal, but it does it's job.

Comment: As for the downvote, people are allowed to "disagree" here on Meta, it's par for the course :)